# Querying a specific field of data out of a CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a specific field of data to pull during a query. But I have run into a CLOB my column that I am trying to pull is "record_number" but it is housed in the `custom` CLOB on the `employee` table.

```
SELECT custom FROM employee;
RUN
7 01/27/1972,8/23/1995511,1F>1**10688992**)2051.758020
```

Custom  CLOB fields:

```
dob,
Emp_StartDate, 
elm_qual,
highly_qualified_subjects, 
gender,
certified, 
**record_number,** 
emp_state_id,
cp_user_id,
change_password,
```

I want to return a result with only the 8 digit string that is bold in the query result.

I am brand new to SQL and I am learning a ton and picking up fairly quickly, but this is stumping me.

Comment: Your data structure is unclear. Is that what the string in the clob looks like? Missing some comma's? Or is it fixed widths? Any reason you're storing this data in a clob?

Comment: Also, please tag correctly. What has [oracle-apex] to do with this question? If you're running this sql on an oracle db, then tag as such. Apex is a dev tool and the sql workshop runs on the oracle db just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this url :-
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1078806?start=0&tstart=0

Create the function it mentions, 
create a loop giving you a line for each call then use the substr function to gather what you want.

Comment: jflack  02-Jun-2010 20:47  (in response to 112514